# HP Proliant DL320 G5 Memory Registered or Unregistered?

Tags: memory, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, ecc

I have an old HP Proliant DL320 G5 with 2x 1GB of RAM. I would like to swap out the old ram and install 4x 2GB of RAM to bring it to the max capacity. The manual calls for PC2-5300 unbuffered modules.

The current RAM label reads: 1GB 2Rx8 PC2-5300E-555-12 HYMP512U72CP8-Y5 AB-C 0716. I know this means they are 1GB DDR2 PC2-5300 unbuffered with ECC. However, when I search eBay, Amazon or other sites, I find parts labeled PC2-5300R or PC2-5300P and the description reads that they are unbuffered and registered with ECC.

What I would like to know, if I fill all the DIMMs in my Server with PC2-5300R, PC2-5300P or PC2-5300 unbuffered, registered with ECC, if the Server will accept the RAM modules, or if I need to have PC2-5300 unbuffered, unregistered with ECC?

Comment: This is how my memory looks: http://www.esklep.world-it.pl/galerie/p/pamiec-hynix-4gb-4-x-1gb_4845.jpg

Comment: This is one of the choices I was looking into: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kingston-8GB-4x2GB-PC2-5300-DDR-ECC-Memory-Registered-Server-KTH-XW9400K2-4G-/111189701484?pt=US_Memory_RAM_&hash=item19e36c336c

Answer (score 2):

Here are the [HP Quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12572_na/12572_na.PDF) for your ProLiant DL320 G5 server.

You only have three RAM options for this server. It's an old machine and only has *four* DIMM slots.

I would ONLY use the HP RAM part numbers for this system; **432806-B21**, **432804-B21** and **432803-B21**. If you're buying used from eBay, search for those part numbers.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For detailed specifications about your server, check the above post by @ewwhite.

Your server supports only Unbuffered/unregistered ECC memory so installing any other kind like Registered ECC or Fully buffered ECC or Non-ECC will not work. So stick with Unbuffered ECC memory only.

Note: Registered ECC (PC2-5300**R**), Unbuffered ECC (PC2-5300**E**), Fully Buffered ECC (PC2-5300**F**) memory do not work when they are mixed with each other in the same server. So make sure you are not mixing Registered ECC and Unbuffered ECC in the same server or with Fully Buffered ECC memory.